# norm ^E command works when I type it manually, but fails in an autoloaded vim file. Why?

Tags: autocmd, scrolling

(Vim 8.0, Windows 7)

I wanted to make an autocmd for loading a certain file, that scrolls down five lines from the beginning of the file. It does other things too, so the autocmd itself (inside of an `augroup filetype`, incidentally) is

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile foo.txt   so $VIM/foo.vim
```

where `foo.vim` contains various other commands, plus:

```
norm! 5^E
```

If I run the above `norm` command manually, it does exactly what I want. However, when I use the autocmd, the buffer ends up with the cursor on line 5, but with line 1 still visible. I get the same behavior if I replace `^E` with `^D`. Nothing also seems to happen if I follow either one with `z^M`.

I could find nothing in the documentation for `au`, `so`, `^E`, or `norm` that addresses this. Is it a bug? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Works fine for me. You sure you did `Ctrl-V + Ctrl-E` in the file with `au`?

Comment: Very sure. I have syntax highlighting on, and the `^E` is clearly a different color. Also, the cursor is going down that many spaces, so I know it's doing *something* with that command.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have a non-zero value for `'scrolloff'`. This forces a minimum number of lines to be visible above/below the cursor. A value of 5 or more in this case would result in exactly the behavior you mention: cursor in the right place but top of the file still visible. A quick-and-diry test would be to just `:set scrolloff=0` right before the `au` command.

If, indeed, `'scrolloff'` appears to be non-zero but you are not setting it yourself then are you using a personal vimrc file? If *not*, note that Vim 8 has new behavior where it will source `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` automatically if user vimrc is not found and in that file `'scrolloff'` is set to 5.

I have no idea if this is what's happening to you but it seems like a plausible theory. Plus, there's some generally useful info here, e.g. probably not a lot of people know about the new "defaults.vim" behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sadly, I'm sure neither of these is the culprit. First, if I run `5^E` manually, even with a `norm!` command, it works, so the scrolloff would have to be set somehow in my vimrc afterward, and it's not (I have a vimrc, and it has no scroll settings, and sources nothing but one file with no scroll settings). Also, I have put in several different values - 2, 5, 10, 20 - for the scroll, and one of them should have worked no matter what the scrolloff was. // Secondly, this problem was happening under Vim 7.3 - I had just installed 8.0 since I saw a few scrolling bugs fixed.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Maybe you can try it with a baseline, all-defaults user vimrc. Just the following: `unlet! skip_defaults_vim` + `source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` + your `au` command. And add `set scrolloff=0`. That could tell us a thing or two depending on the result.

Comment: That changed something. My vim window (which now looks very bare) scrolled properly. I left out the scrolloff setting, too. // Now trying to decide how to proceed. I could try the painstaking process of adding my original vimrc to this default, little by little. Hmm.

Comment: ....and, done. Nothing in my _vimrc seems to have caused that scroll behavior, and now it's working correctly. But if I take out the unlet and the defaults, the behavior returns. So perhaps this is the answer.

Comment: You say you "left out the scrolloff setting, too" and it still worked? That doesn't seem right. Here's what I see... First, I follow my steps exactly and result is correct and expected: line 5 at top of window. If then remove just `set scrolloff=0` then it's in the "bad" state: cursor line 5 but line 1 at top of window. Have you tried with file other than `.vim` suffix? Try a file with `.txt` after modifying the `au` command appropriately. Could be default settings applied to `.vim`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, sidetracked... // I'm not sure what you mean by "tried with file other than `.vim` suffix". Do you mean renaming `foo.vim` to `foo.txt`? I just tried that; no effect. // Thanks for the help so far; I'm kinda interested academically in this problem now. I should read up on `skip_defaults_vim`.